# How do I create a form letter where some text is not printed if a field on a Google form is left blank

Tags: google-apps-script

My company recently switched to Google Apps and I am trying to covert Word and Excel docs to Google Docs. I am completely new to Google App Script and am stuck. I have been searching for a few days a have not found what I am looking for.

I have a Google form that is emailed to a sales person. After it is completed the Google spreadsheet is updated and then sends a form letter to the sales person summarizing their input. Some of the fields on the form are optional. How do I create a template that does not include some of the form letter text if the question was left unanswered?

For example, one of the optional fields is for a customer website address, if the customer does not have a website I don’t want the words website to show up on the form.

If anyone has any “For Dummies” instructions on how to do this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Business Review Report
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1gRk2irahyW2Sf4pQMTDykXlMQqYgbe1Ba1vkh20KDYo";
var docName = "Business Review";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit (e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var variablename = "static entry or form value"
var email_address = e.values[1];
var Business_Name = e.values[2];
var Business_Address = e.values[3];
var Phone_Number = e.values[4]
var Email_address = e.values[5];
var Website = e.values[6];
var Participants = e.values[7];
var Agenda = e.values[8];
var Updates_and_Progress1 = e.values[9]; 
var Updates_and_Progress2 = e.values[10];
var Updates_and_Progress3 = e.values[11]; 
var Current_Issues1 = e.values[12]; 
var Current_Issues2 = e.values[13]; 
var Current_Issues3 = e.values[14]; 
var Next_Steps = e.values[15]; 

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+ Business_Name)
.getId();

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyBusinessName', Business_Name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyBusinessAddress', Business_Address);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPhoneNumber', Phone_Number);
copyBody.replaceText('keyEmailaddress', email_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keywebsite', Website);
copyBody.replaceText('keyParticipants', Participants);
copyBody.replaceText('keyAgenda', Agenda);
copyBody.replaceText('keyUpdatesAndProjects1', Updates_and_Progress1);
copyBody.replaceText('keyUpdatesAndProjects2', Updates_and_Progress2);
copyBody.replaceText('keyUpdatesAndProjects3', Updates_and_Progress3);
copyBody.replaceText('keyCurrentIssues1',Current_Issues1);
copyBody.replaceText('keyCurrentIssues2', Current_Issues2);
copyBody.replaceText('keyCurrentIssues3', Current_Issues3);
copyBody.replaceText('keyNextSteps', Next_Steps);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Business Review";
var body = "Business Review for " + Business_Name + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);

}
```

It works, but the resulting PDF also includes text for the unfilled fields like CurrentIssues2.

I am not sure if I am explaining this clearly so please respond with any questions and I will try to be more clear.

Thanks again,
Lisa

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the google templates work, but look at http://google-ctemplate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/guide.html... Maybe breaking out temporary bits to sections that are conditionally shown will work. (Something along the lines of "if (Website != "") { //show Website section }")

Comment: @Charx Thanks for the respone. I am looking at the site right now. It's a little over my head because I don't know how to program in any language. I'm hoping I can use your link to help me find a more beginner level explanation. But thank you for giving me a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your form questions apparently have default values that you don't want in your form letter. You can check for those defaults and replace them with something more suitable, such as a blank string.

```
...
// If website question was not answered, leave blank
var Website = e.values[6];
if (Website == 'website') Website = '';
...
```

This alternative uses the Ternary or [Conditional Operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and is more compact:

```
...
// If website question was not answered, leave blank
var Website = (e.values[6] == 'website') ? '' : e.values[6];
...
```